# Express.js res.json appending to response object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I'm trying to return some json data using the res.json() function from Express, but instead of returning a new json object each time it seems that it's appending to the old json object each time. This means that I'm receiving duplicate data in the same response object.

My code looks like this:

```
await Promise.all(promises)
.then(responses => res.json(responses))
.catch(error => console.error(error))
```

Returned data example:

```
[
[data]
]
```

Second request returned data sample:

```
[
[data],
[data(1)]
]
```

My code returns a list of responses which I want, but on repeated requests to the same function the new response is appended to the data from the old response and sent back. Is this intended? Am I doing something wrong?

*edit*: here is the rest of my code for context. I'm new to js and async programming so let me know if something I'm doing is terribly wrong.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const authFunctions = require('./auth')
var bearer_token
const space_id = 11111
let id_promises = []


async function get_category_rooms(category_id)
{
    return fetch(`https://url.com/api/${category_id}`,
    {
        headers:

        {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${bearer_token}`
        }
    }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => data.map(category => category.items))
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
}

async function get_category_ids() {
    return fetch(`https://url.com/api/${space_id}`,
    {
        headers:
        {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${bearer_token}`
        }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data =>
        {
            categories = data[0]["categories"].filter(category => category.name !== "category i don't want")
            categories.forEach(category_item =>
            {
                id_promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
                {
                    resolve(get_category_rooms(category_item.cid))
                }))
            })
        })
}

async function get_room_bookings(room_id) {
    return fetch(`https://url.com/api/${room_id}`,
    {
        headers:
        {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${bearer_token}`
        }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => data)
}
async function get_not_group_room_reservations(req,res)
{
    let room_promises = []
    if (!await authFunctions.auth_check(bearer_token))
    {
        console.log('invalid bearer token. changing bearer')
        bearer_token = await authFunctions.auth()
    }
    await get_category_ids()
    let rooms = await Promise.all(id_promises)
    .then(responses =>
        {
            let room_ids = responses.flat(2)
            room_ids.forEach(room_id =>
            {
                room_promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
                    {
                        resolve(get_room_bookings(room_id))
                    }))
            })
        })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
    await Promise.all(room_promises)
        .then(responses => res.json(responses))
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
}
```

Comment: can you provide more code to understand more clearly

Comment: @sabbir I've added a pastebin link to my code. Thank you

Comment: @Phil I've added a pastebin link with much more detailed code. ```promises``` contains a number of fetch requests that have yet to be completed. Thank you

Comment: [**copy the code into the question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use Stack Snippets to make a live demo of inline JavaScript / HTML / CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Phil Thank you for pointing me towards that rule. Assumed I was in the right without reading the rules entirely. Sorry about that. I've posted the rest of my code within the question body.

Comment: Where is `room_promises` defined? I see `room_promises.push()` but no definition / initialisation. This is probably your problem

Comment: I suggest you move `let room_promises = []` **inside** your `get_not_group_room_reservations` function

Comment: I promise this is my last code edit. I left out initializations, but I realize now everybody else is reading this code for the first time so it's necessary to explicitly show my initializations. I do all of these just above the first function definition.

Comment: @Phil Thank you for the advice. I've moved room_promises initializations into ```get_not_group_room_reservations()``` (that definitely makes more sense than where I had it) but the problem still persists.

Comment: Please update the code in your question

Comment: I suspect you're going to run in to a similar problem with `id_promises`

Comment: Ohhhh I totally undersand what you mean now. Because they were being declared globally they're still full during the second call. I'll check if this works. Thank you!

Comment: @Phil you were totally right. I've switched to declaring ```room_promises``` in ```get_not_group_room_reservations``` and declaring ```id_promises``` in ```get_category_ids```. Then I return the value of ```id_promises``` in a ```.then(() => id_promises)```. Thank you for your help!